# Why is a map defined as $A \rightarrow V^\dagger A V$ for all V completely positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators, positive-semidefinite

In this [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271586/1-s2.0-S0024379500X02509/1-s2.0-0024379575900750/main.pdf?x-amz-security-token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEB8aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDKNj8mLUBvPWajCJq1niyNMh9Y2uRJvSR5dTEkRQfo1QIhAJjjb1jcP6wwDpXrpqKIrwokmaGQXst6PPYd4p%2BOhYe0KtoDCEcQAhoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgwGhchQfT9UQIisH9wqtwOASZauxaSE55H6zENtmxCScG54WER%2B2Cu%2Fp9Qsy7T9GnLX07qjDFiP6hkM0D7LvuTwRMMtPtR8Sfis21FTNEmP6rDHSRPETDKRyxeISluTgmQV7k%2FoqSjR3ch5fqSWWNbcKK5QyETD5bwa0d9XIhxYwPO4vmDag0RJnaL%2Byc%2B2%2Bm0bIDhhDDELFjs%2BUhpeyGurK543r71E52W5r5exwzKL6Yti%2FI2TTp1FxGPTjM8kmQHLdtNv8B2e8DsGxFwnRicEWCpUt8KPcTwiTB5ZsGEVhpyDb2QM9A1hxnsJAraHoU2RryEH6Ruxkun9RE%2FF6L5%2FtAq3lLAJptoITCFJByMiz2ocOdYu07GkwuRTsOpCspNdUodkRb5oAD%2BO4N%2FEt6oyufBpoHWL15rNt1hiyPXHmFhbmnlVBQaEheLRFSXSdRqgJl7w8T%2F4YiYmIIL6rBmkaZO0wzaZpNUx9d3F1b6ZQoi%2B7NuJGBfvad5hmECpTuqy9CBoLEwOWmj%2FbVF4HxsSoZjP%2BRaUo6NFY%2FGFXPVCVulIcMOKaxzcucpgjwl0iDcmvIcPAA74XZQIy45ELGn9Lpn6CfsPMPjj6ecFOrMB5YtHyNTjQGi3Etbl4siyCgAp4NyuohDd8bpt9q4hGtqDmDCPcX2EqsVa%2FG%2FS1pQDpjpXoukGZbbYVYbp53KNZ5DVaUJyWXz8A1oyY1V2NYplmtLKJ1Fyr656Lg8InS5qzhZhlVLl4Gnl4%2BDe8DfX65VPst0q7Ro5JBDhhVCQekgB8Z4be9TZYIl5jgi8Uf4o9j3Qn1Rtipkaz8p%2B2nSWaaD%2FTqfetu1pTrkugRaF2G3oVWs%3D&AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAQ3PHCVTY525RSY6C&Expires=1559921642&Signature=T7p8EWnutErr1L3FDB0bJT%2BM2%2Fo%3D&hash=c748253bc4872dbfd731894f438a3acf188bbc7b34bd0d96f34fbf506b1a08c6&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0024379575900750&tid=spdf-a114d558-2ce7-4854-b870-133381b28245&sid=6edd01b26a33a1464b1b5741a7b9a5fcc5c8gxrqb&type=client) by M. D. Choi, he claims,

> For each $n * m$ matrix $V$, it is evident that the map: $M_n \rightarrow M_m$ with $A \rightarrow V^\dagger A V$ is completely positive.

$M_x$ denotes all $x*x$ complex matrices.

I can see why such a map would be positive, as one can diagonalise write the matrices such that $A$ is diagonal, and we know that $V^\dagger V$ is positive, so multiplying would cause it to remain positive.

But how would one prove that such a map is completely positive?

Answer (score 1):

One equivalent criterion for the positivity of a complex square matrix $M$ is that $v^\dagger Mv\ge0$ for every vector $v$. Now, let $x^\dagger=(x_1^\dagger,x_2^\dagger,\ldots,x_p^\dagger)$ and $y^\dagger=(x_1^\dagger V^\dagger,x_2^\dagger V^\dagger,\ldots,x_p^\dagger V^\dagger)$, where $x_i\in\mathbb C^m$ for each $i$. Then
$$
x^\dagger \left(V^\dagger A_{ij}V\right)_{1\le i,j\le p}\,x
=y^\dagger \left(A_{ij}\right)_{1\le i,j\le p}\,y
\ge0
$$
whenever the block matrix $\left(A_{ij}\right)_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,p\}}$ is positive. Hence $A\mapsto V^\dagger AV$ is completely positive.

Answer (score 1):

If $\phi(A) = V^\dagger A V$, then we find that
$$
\begin{align}
(\phi \otimes \operatorname{id}_{M_k})(A \otimes B) &= \phi(A) \otimes B = (V^\dagger A V) \otimes B 
\\ & = (V \otimes \operatorname{id}_{\Bbb C^k}) (A \otimes B)(V \otimes \operatorname{id}_{\Bbb C^k})^\dagger
\end{align}
$$
so that $(\phi \otimes \operatorname{id}_{M_k})(C) = (V \otimes \operatorname{id}_{\Bbb C^k}) C(V \otimes \operatorname{id}_{\Bbb C^k})^\dagger$.  It follows that $\phi \otimes \operatorname{id}_{M_k}$ is a positive map for all $k$, which is to say that $\phi$ is completely positive.